# How to control Servo-Motor from Arduino with Raspberry

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

at the moment I am using a Servo-Motor and two Motors. My goal is that if I execute the script, it should first start the motors, then turning the Servo-Motor at 30 degrees, waiting 3 seconds, turning the servo motor at his initial start and after 10 seconds the motors should stop. 
However, my motors start without any problems but the Servo-Motor tries to make a 180 ° 
and both motors stop at the same time
Here you can see my code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
#import
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from picamera import PiCamera

#Variables
in1 = 17
in2 = 27
in3 = 23
in4 = 24

enA = 22
enB = 25

spd = 15

servoMotor = 5


#Setup
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(in1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(in2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(in3, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(in4, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(enA, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(enB, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(servoMotor, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.setup(in1, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.setup(in2, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.setup(in3, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.setup(in4, GPIO.LOW)



#Variable 
a = GPIO.PWM(enA,1000)
b = GPIO.PWM(enB,1000)
#PWM with 50Hz
servoP = GPIO.PWM(servoMotor, 50) 
#Starting
a.start(spd)
b.start(spd)
servoP.start(0)

#Code
GPIO.output(in1, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(in2, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(in3, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(in4, GPIO.LOW)
sleep(10)
GPIO.output(in1, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(in2, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(in3, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(in4, GPIO.LOW)
servoP.ChangeDutyCycle(15)
sleep(3)
servoP.ChangeDutyCycle(7.5)
servoP.stop()
```

Comment: Perhaps better on https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Marged or https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Sounds like you might have a continuous rotation (CR) servo. Even if you don't, all servos have different PWN ranges, so what servo you are using is a detail I would need to give you a better answer (Sorry for asking for clarification in an answer, but I can't comment).</strike>

Try setting your duty cycle to a minimum of 3 and a maximum of 11. That appears to be a better range for the servos you are using. As per the motors, could you please tell me what pins they are connected to?

Comment: I think I should have a TowerPro MicroServo 99 SG90

Comment: @DizzySailor Check to see if your gearbox is stripped or altered, as all sources I can find say that TowerPro MicroServo 99 SG90 is a 180 degree, not CR servo. Speaking anecdotally, the gearbox on that servo is prone to failure.

Comment: Sorry, I controlled my Servo again, and it only makes 180°, not 360.